# Set JAVA_HOME to 1.7 on Windows 7 but need 1.8 for IDEs

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, intellij-idea

My current project requires JDK 1.7 being set to JAVA_HOME on Windows 7 but it appears I need JDK 1.8 to run the latest versions of Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA...

Have set my JAVA_HOME to 1.7 in System Environmental Variables. How can I run IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse using JDK 1.8 but keeping 1.7 as the JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Why do you need `JAVA_HOME` to point to 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

Set JAVA_HOME to 1.8 jre to be able to run Intellij and other stuff on latest java. For your project in Intellij set Project SDK to java 1.7 - follow [this help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html)

[image]